# How can I identify the uniform and other details in this picture of my great grandfather circa 1913?

Tags: identification, uniform, german

This is a picture of my great grandfather circa 1913. How can I identify the uniform and any other details from it?

[image]

He came to the US in 1913. Was married approximately 1909 in Pirmasens. His port of departure was Baden.

Comment: Can you give us any more details on your grandfather? For example, you have used the tag 'german'. How do you know it is German? The more you can tell us, the more likely it is that someone will be able to help you.

Comment: You may have more luck here: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but possibly Bavarian infantry? The picture seems very much washed out, with little detail visible.

Comment: This is a cool opportunity. The question isn't "What is this uniform?", but "How can I study this?" -  (of course the first answer is what @LarsBosteen noted - assemble as much context as possible).  But H:SE has plenty of experts with knowledge & skills to advise the *how*.

Comment: @njuffa - After zooming, I suspect its actually a painting.

Comment: (@T.E.D. No, this is not a painting, these are artifacts from lossfull digitization procedures.) If you have the original of that picture, please scan it again at the highest possible resolution, with the most available colors. If your scan software tries to apply any sort of post-processing "filter" or "optimization", **turn them off**. Save the result as a .jpeg image with the highest available quality setting, **and then do nothing to change the resulting file**. Every attempt you make to "improve" the result will only result in loss of information.

Comment: @ccprog (It may have been somewaht soft in the original, although probably not _this_ soft, and we don't know how many analog steps this had (repro?)) That is mostly good & needed advice: however, the upload limit is at 2MB, so a compromise toward that goal needs to be found. Ideal: flatbed scan, max physical resolution of that scanner, then no additional  processing, exclusively watching for filesize to minimally below 2MB when converting to jpeg.

Comment: I know this may sound like we're asking a lot of extra work, but if you have access to the original I'd suggest doing it. A good picture with your cellphone camera would probably be an improvement, and you'd be absolutely amazed what people here can figure out about a uniform by looking closely at the details on the buttons.

Comment: @T.E.D. I think you were right about it being a painting. The cloth on the stool behind looks painted in a simpler style to the man. Lossfull digitisation would have a more uniform pattern to the lace with thinner lines - such as the ends of the moustache. I would expect a painting to be in colour though. Perhaps it's a portrait sized copy of a photo. The picture has been taken with a cellphone because you can see the reflection of it at the bottom of the picture. A close up of the jacket with buttons would be good in any case.

Comment: Thanks for all of the suggestions, I will work on getting my hands on the picture

Comment: @DamionKeeling - Try zooming on stuff like the creases and edges too. It just looks too organic. Like someone was trying to depict order, rather than an existing order getting fuzzed out.

Answer (score 6):

The details that are discernible are few, and the lack of detail overall a major hinderance.

With only a rough year range (per marriage date between 1908–1913) and two firm locations identified with "[Pirmasens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirmasens)" and "Baden", we may conclude that this is a German army uniform. But while [Baden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baden) would have its own army and uniform, Pirmasens was then part of 'Bavarian Palatinate' ([Circle of the Rhine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_the_Rhine)).

However, looking at this in steps and going from top to bottom, listing the available information seems to provide a few additional pointers:

## Head gear

Two round [cockades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockade) above each other usually indicate German Imperial Army, usually [colour coded like this:](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kokarde_(Abzeichen))

[image]

## Shoulder boards

## Collar

Stand-up collr

## Cuffs

'Brandenburg style' cuffs (three buttons as cuff links, less decorated then French style)

## Tunic

Overall, not for combat, but [Mess dress uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mess_dress_uniform)
Style, buttons,

seven buttons visible

## Gloves

## Trousers

## Sidearm

Some kind of "knife", perhaps a bayonet, but too blurry to be sure.

## Decorations

The shoulder boards *should* hint at the unit, the collar decorations as well.

The sidearm often had quite distinctive [tassels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tassel) attached, specific for units.

Other decorations, for example for specialties or distinctions, rank seem all missing.

## External hints

One picture for comparison, pointing again towards Baden origin?
[image]
[ebay: "Orig. Foto-AK MANNHEIM Soldaten, Ausgeh-Uniform, Gebäude 1913"](https://www.ebay.de/itm/264709464237)